# How to add sales.js in this xml file in Magent2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I want to override **module\sales\view\adminhtml\web\js\order\create\scripts.js** in my Custom Module. So, generally i asked question, How to add **sales.js** file in this xml.

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
    <reference name="billing_method">
        <block type="module_namespace/customer_account" name="use_wallet" template="vendor/module/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml" />
    </reference>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
            <file>module/namespace/mage/adminhtml/sales.js</file>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
```

Comment: code provide by you. is magento1 code. Please try magento two code.

Comment: This question looks related to M1 Why m2 tags were there , clear that then only I will cast reopen vote

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of adding a js file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="sales.js"/>
    </head>
    <reference name="billing_method">
        <block type="module_namespace/customer_account" name="use_wallet" template="module/namespace/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml" />
    </reference>
</page>
```

You do not have to declare that it is a file for admin because you have the XML file in the admin path:
`/app/code/Vendorname/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/sales.js`

Answer (score 0):

Create `vendor/module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml` and add

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Vendor_Module::js/sales.js" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="billing_method">
            <block type="vendor/module/customer/account" name="use_wallet" template="Vendor_Module::checkout/onepage/payment.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your  **js** file in **vendor/module/view/adminhtml/web/js/sales.js**

and then call it in your xml file.

```
<head>   
   <script src="Vendor_Module::js/sales.js"/>
</head>
```